# Use TypeScript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tsx

I am learning React with Typescript. I have a `view` like below.

**index.tsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import { CButton } from '@coreui/react'
import { useHistory } from 'react-router'

const Team = () => {
    const history = useHistory()
    const handleNewMember = () => {
        history.push('/team/add-member')
    }
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="page-title">
                <CButton color="primary" className="long-btn" onClick={handleNewMember}>
                    Add a New Member
                </CButton>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default React.memo(Team)
```

I have below code in `route.ts` file

```
const AddMember = React.lazy(() => import('./views/team/add-member'))

const routes = [
    { path: '/team/add-member', exact: true, name: 'Add Team Member', component: AddMember },
]

export default routes
```

When I click on the button I can see URL `http://localhost:3000/#/team/add-member` at address bar of browser. But I can't see the View (HTML).

What is the solution ?

Comment: Can we see your `Router`? This probably doesn't apply to TypeScript. It is more like _"Why my app isn't routing?"_ instead of _"Use TyeScript in React"_.

Comment: Thanks @Jax-p. I am new in React as well as Typescript. Where can I find `Router` ? Thanks.

Comment: Couple things: 1) why not simple export Team (instead of the memoized version), 2) try rending a simple <button /> instead of the one from coreui

Answer (score 1):

Because `handleNewMember` is an async function.

Comment: Thanks @Hamidreza. I removed `async` but it is not working. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu Can I see your `BrowserRouter`?

Comment: Thanks @Hamidreza. Where can I find `BrowserRouter` ?

Comment: @abuabu Where did you use this `routes` array?

Comment: Thanks @Hamidreza. I used `routes` array in `ContentRoute.tsx` file like below. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCw5D.png

Comment: @abuabu Try to render a simple component instead of `AddMember` to see if it works.

Comment: @abuabu May I see the code for `./views/team/add-member` component?